# how to translate javascript child inheritance into python

Tags: javascript, python

I'm having trouble translating the following JavaScript code into python. My problem is inheriting the parent properties and methods in the ChildNode class by using `super.__init__()`. In js, you just call `super()` and get all the props. It doesn't seem to be the same in python. The super function is demanding to have val and key inside the parenthesis but I'm not sure how that would work because Im getting val from the `ChildNode.__init__` function

JS CODE that does what I want

```
class BinarySearchTree {
    constructor(val, key) {
        this.val = val;
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null;
        this.key = key;
    }

    insert(val) {
        const currNode = this;

        if (val === currNode.val) return null;

        if (val < currNode.val) {
            if (!currNode.left) {
                currNode.left = new ChildNode(val);
                return this;
            } else {
                currNode.left.insert(val);
            }
        }

        if (val > currNode.val) {
            if (!currNode.right) {
                currNode.right = new ChildNode(val);
                return this;
            } else {
                currNode.right.insert(val);
            }
        }
    }
}

class ChildNode extends BinarySearchTree {
    constructor(val) {
        super();
        this.val = val;

        delete this.key;
    }
}

var root = new BinarySearchTree(20, 14);
root.insert(8);
root.insert(22);
root.insert(4);
console.log(root);
```

Python attempt

```
class BinarySearchTree:
    def __init__(self, val: int, key: int):
        self.val = val
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.key = key

    def insert(self, val):
        currNode = self

        if val == currNode.val:
            return None

        if val < currNode.val:
            if not currNode.left:
                currNode.left = ChildNode(val)
                return self
            else:
                currNode.left.insert(val)

        if val > currNode.val:
            if not currNode.right:
                currNode.right = ChildNode(val)
                return self
            else:
                currNode.right.insert(val)

# having trouble inheriting here
class ChildNode(BinarySearchTree):
    def __init__(self, val):
        super().__init__()
        self.val = val

        del self.key


root = BinarySearchTree(20, 14)
root.insert(8)
root.insert(22)
root.insert(4)
print(root)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript if you do not pass parameters to a function it defaults them to being `undefined`, however, this is not tolerated by Python. If you run your code you will notice you get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 41, in <module>
    root.insert(8)
  File "main.py", line 17, in insert
    currNode.left = ChildNode(val)
  File "main.py", line 34, in __init__
    super().__init__()
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'val' and 'key'
```

Which is very helpful because it tells us that the `super.__init__()` call is missing two arguments, which are defined in the super class.

If you intend to replicate the JS behaviour then you would do well to add a default `None` to the arguments in the constructor of the superclass.

```py
class BinarySearchTree:
    def __init__(self, val: int = None, key: int = None):
        self.val = val
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.key = key
```

Answer (score 1):

The child class's `__init__` method needs to pass the appropriate arguments in the `super().__init__()` call.

```
# having trouble inheriting here
class ChildNode(BinarySearchTree):
    def __init__(self, val: int):
        super().__init__(val, '')

        del self.key
```

You don't need to do `self.val = val` in the child class, since that's done by the parent class.

That said, this doesn't seem like an appropriate class hierarchy in either language. You shouldn't delete attributes in the child class, because any inherited methods that depend on it will fail.

Comment: Well I wanted the BinarySearchTree instance to have the key property but I didn't want the childNode to inherit that property. I didn't know if there was a way to selectively inherit properties from the parent so I just deleted that key prop for every ChildNode instance

Comment: Subclasses are for IS-A relationships. This seems like a HAS-A relationship -- a binary search tree contains child nodes. A child node is not a kind of search tree.

Comment: Remember that subclasses must satisfy the Liskov Substitution Principle.

Comment: So that means I should include the key property in all my ChildNode instances?

Comment: @RonnyFitzgerald then you **don't want inheritance**

Comment: @RonnyFitzgerald no, that means **you shouldn't use inheritance**

Comment: @RonnyFitzgerald Normally the child nodes of a BST are more BSTs. You don't really need two different classes.